# glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES Fails with GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: 3d, opengl-es-2.0, egl

On GPU MALI 400 MP the glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES fails with GL_INVALID_OPERATION gl error.
We have checked the same on MALI-T760 and glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES returns GL_NO_ERROR.

Result of glGetERROR()
1) returns GL_NO_ERROR just before glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES call.
2) returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION  just after glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES call.

Any input on how to fix this GL_INVALID_ERRROR will be helpfull.

Comment: Most likely the driver does not recognize the format of the image. Do you know what format your external image has? If your device supports the KHR_debug extension you may be able to get a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks Jan. You are right there is some issue with gpu drivers